# how to remove textfield using dom

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom

I have a form that permits to user to add `textfield` whenever he click on a button
I want to add link below every added `textfield` that allow to remove it

here is the script

```
   <script>

function myFunction() {
      let wrapper = document.getElementById("dynamic-question");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var del = document.createElement("button");
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      del.className = "del"
      del.innerText = "X"

      div.appendChild(input)
      div.appendChild(del)
      div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      wrapper.appendChild(div)
    }

    document.getElementById("dynamic-question").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
      if (e.target.className=="del") {
        e.target.closest("div").remove()
      }
    })
</script>
```

and here the html code

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="./gett">
<label for="question"> Question </label> <br>
<input class="champ" type="textarea" name="question" id="question" value=""><br><br>

<label for="ans"> Answers </label> <br>

<input type="text" name="ans1" id="ans1" value=""><br><br>

<input type="text" name="ans2" id="ans2" value=""><br><br>

    <div id="dynamic-question"></div> 

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add proposition</button> <br><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating link like button, you can attach a function to that button to remove like the following way:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById("dynamic-question");

  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var btn  = document.createElement("button");
  btn.textContent = "Remove";
  btn.addEventListener('click', remove);
  wrapper.appendChild(input);
  wrapper.appendChild(btn);
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
function remove(){
  this.previousSibling.remove(); //Remove the input
  this.nextSibling.remove();     //Remove the first br
  this.nextSibling.remove();     //Remove the second br
  this.remove();                 //Remove the button
}
```

```css
button:not(:first-child) {
  background:none!important;
  color:inherit;
  border:none; 
  padding:0!important;
  font: inherit;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>

<div id="dynamic-question"></div>
```

Comment: This is identical to my example

Comment: good job ;) but I have a remark : 
if I add for example 3 text fields and then remove them all
and later I click again on the button it add a text field at the fourth position. how to overcome this problem ???

Comment: @jan, yes, you are right. I forgot to remove the 2 `br` element created. Updated the answer, please check.....thanks:)

Comment: @Mamun thanks, what if I wanted to remove a none next sibling but another one created in top of the function

Answer (score 2):

1. type=button on the add
2. e.preventDefault() on the button to delete OR make type=button too
3. Use a container for the input, the BRs and the delete to get rid of them all in one go

Then call [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```js
function myFunction() {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById("dynamic-question");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var del = document.createElement("button");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  del.className = "del";
  del.innerText = "X";
  del.type="button";
  
  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(del);
  div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById("dynamic-question").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (e.target.className=="del") {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.closest("div").remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
<div id="dynamic-question"></div>
```

Individually  like this - all nearest siblings needs to be removed including the BRs

```js
function myFunction() {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById("dynamic-question");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var del = document.createElement("button");
  del.className = "del";
  del.type="buttpn"
  del.innerText = "X";
  
  wrapper.appendChild(input);
  wrapper.appendChild(del);
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}

document.getElementById("dynamic-question").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (e.target.className=="del") {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.target.previousElementSibling.remove(); // remove field
    e.target.nextElementSibling.remove(); // remove br
    e.target.nextElementSibling.remove(); // remove br
    e.target.remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
<div id="dynamic-question"></div>
```

Comment: I tried 'run code snippet' and it's working, but when I try it in my code I got this'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: obviously related to java

Comment: I'll add the whole jsp page as same as u suggested  maybe it can help

Comment: see the changes above

Comment: then what it is ?

Comment: i know it's html but i save it by extention .jsp I got the error when I click on the button that remove the textfield

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 28,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 46

Comment: @jan I am very disappointed that you did not accept my answer - it was first, it was complete and gave you two versions to play with. The other answer is identical in result but not as elegant as mine since I delegate and have one event handler and he has one event handler per button. the issues with the buttons were due to incomplete information at the time of writing the first script

Comment: it's not about you or him . I'm thankful to you that you had invested time and effort into answering my question but even the edits you did the error persists...
although I indicated it as useful answer

Comment: There should be no errors with my latest code. The original issues came about due to lack of initial example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an element from the DOM like so:

> To remove a specified element without having to specify its parent node:

```
function removeEl(id) {
  let node = document.getElementById(id);
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

So, in your case, you may want to add an ID when you are creating the textfield, so you are able to find it again and then remove it:

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById("dynamic-question");

  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  // Add id here
  input.id = "[id_here]"


  wrapper.appendChild(input)
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
</script>
```

Then you can call the function above like so:

```
removeEl("[id_here]")
```

Comment: You know you can click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create an example? Anyway I answered the question fully

Comment: You just needed a button and a container :)

Comment: True :p I was just answering a different question so I quickly finished this one 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For each element you dynamically add, create a div and add a remove link with some class, then add a listener that when user clicks on the remove link, it removes the element, and the parent element (the div that the link and the input are inside).

```js
//annonymous function
var btnAddField = document.getElementById("btnAddField");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

btnAddField.onclick = function() {
var div = document.createElement('div');
 var input = document.createElement("input");
  var removeLink = document.createElement("a");
  removeLink.innerHTML = 'Remove input';
  removeLink.className = "btn-remove";
  div.append(input);
  div.append(removeLink)
  wrapper.append(div);
};

 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.className == 'btn-remove'){
          e.target.parentNode.remove();
     }
 });
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<button id="btnAddField">
 Add input field
</button>
</div>
```